# Passing Parameters from Javascript to flask python script

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, flask

Currently I have a angularjs file which uses $http.get to call my python flask script.

In this flask script I want to then call another python script (which is running pySolr), however the http.get call contains a parameter I wish to pass to this pySolr script.

Is there any documentation on this/ can it actually be done?

```
$http.get('http://localhost:5000/python/solr', "$scope.tag");
console.log($scope.tag);
```

$scope.tag is the variable I need to get

My flask file is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/python/solr')
def solr():
    "MY CODE TO CALL SOLR SCRIPT GOES HERE"


if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this using query parameters:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:5000/python/solr?tag=' + $scope.tag);
console.log($scope.tag);
```

In flask

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/python/solr')
def solr():
    print request.args  # should get tag here
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying! I'm having an issue importing request. Is that a flask method?

Comment: oops, it should be ``from flask import request`` i will fix that.  did not test